# Expression filtering based on user input

Tags: qliksense

I wish to aggregate Score * Revenue for the most recent entry per organization, considering only those entries where the date is less or equal to a user-defined variable `vSelectedDate` that is from the `DatePicker` user input in the Sheets editor, **after load script** has completed.

| Organisation Name | Date | Revenue | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 06/02/2024 | 300 | 5 |
| Apple | 06/02/2023 | 200 | 4 |
| Apple | 06/02/2022 | 100 | 3 |
| Banana | 01/01/2024 | 50 | 10 |
| Banana | 01/01/2023 | 70 | 10 |
| Banana | 01/01/2022 | 100 | 11 |

E.g.`vSelectedDate`= 30/12/2023. Desired selection (for visualisation):

| Organisation Name | Date | Revenue | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 06/02/2023 | 200 | 4 |
| Banana | 06/02/2023 | 70 | 10 |

Desired expression result: `200 * 4 + 70 * 10 = 1500`

Is there a possible solution or workaround for what I need?

I have tried:

```
Sum(
  Aggr(
    If(
      Rank(Max(Date)) = 1 and Date <= $(vSelectedDate),
      Score * Revenue
    ),
    [Organisation Name]
  )
)
```

However I understand that it doesn't work because `Max(Date)` needs to be calculated within an aggregated context specific to each `Organisation Name`, but without an explicit aggregation phase separating the determination of `Max(Date)` from its ranking, the expression cannot correctly isolate and rank the latest date per organization.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this expression:

```
Sum(
    Aggr(
         FirstSortedValue({<Date={"<=$(vSelectedDate)"}>} Score * Revenue, -Date) 
    ,[Organisation Name]
   )
 )
```

It works in various kinds of objects like table or KPI:

[image]

Data used:

```
Data:
Load *
Inline [
Organisation Name,  Date,   Revenue,    Score
Apple,  '06.02.2024',   300,    5
Apple,  '06.02.2023',   200,    4
Apple,  '06.02.2022',   100,    3
Banana, '01.01.2024',   50,     10
Banana, '01.01.2023',   70,     10
Banana, '01.01.2022',   100,    11
];
```